# simple_form_for not showing fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a model (Project), in the 'new' action I have this code

```
<h1>Create new project</h1>
<% simple_form_for @project, :url => create_project_path  do |project_form| %>
<%= project_form.error_messages %>
<ul>
    <% project_form.input :name %>
    <% project_form.input :subdomain %>

    <% project_form.input :allow_email_report_client %>
    <% project_form.input :allow_email_post_client %>

    <% project_form.submit %>
</ul>
   <% end%>
```

the controller code is simple
I have a `load_and_authorize_resource` (using CanCan) and the action code is this

```
def new
@project = Project.new
end
```

now, I do get a  tag rendered but no fields inside this form

I have the exact same thing for Account model and there all of the fields are shown with no problem.

does anyone have an idea what is the problem?

Comment: It would help if you can post the new action for the projects_controller

Comment: I edited the question, added the controller code

Comment: Try restarting the server. Also, are you using Rails 3? Also, if you use the "standard" rails form, then does it work?

Comment: @Zabba - I am using rails 2.3.8, with a regular form_for it's not working as well, same problem.

Comment: @Zabba - it's not working on Edit as well, when I print out @project.name inside the page, I do see the name but the form does not get rendered in edit as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah! You're missing the `=` signs in your fields:

```
<%= project_form.input :name %>
<%= project_form.input :subdomain %>
....
```

Without the `=`, the code within the `<% %>` will run, but there will be no output.

Also, good to know: in Rails 2.x you do not need the `=` for the `form_for` (Rails 3, however does need the `=`)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your new action looks like this:

```
def new
  @project = Project.new
end
```

Comment: my controller action looks just like this